# Problema com left join usando entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Estou com um problema para realizar um left join em asp.net mvc.

Possuo uma *view* que lista todas as telas do sistema, as mesmas estão cadastradas na base de dados.

Criei uma tabela de tipo (aba), tela e as funções da tela.
Estou dando um left join para resgatar os dados das três tabelas.

```
public IQueryable SelectForeignKey(string idEmpresa)
{
    var resultado = from aba in _sigconEntities.Aba
                    join tela in _sigconEntities.Tela on aba.idAba equals tela.idAba
                    join telaFuncao in _sigconEntities.TelaFuncao on tela.idTela equals telaFuncao.idTela
                    where aba.idEmpresa == idEmpresa
                    select new
                    {
                        abaIdAba = aba.idAba,
                        abaNome = aba.Nome,
                        abaIdAbaSistema = aba.idAbaSistema,
                        telaIdTela = tela.idTela,
                        telaIdAba = tela.idAba,
                        telaNome = tela.Nome,
                        telaIdTelaSistema = tela.idTelaSistema,
                        telaFuncaoIdTela = telaFuncao.idTela,
                        telaFuncaoNome = telaFuncao.Nome,
                        telaFuncaoIdFuncaoSistema = telaFuncao.idFuncaoSistema
                    };

    return resultado;
}
```

Estou retornando os dados para o *controller* e salvando em uma *viewbag*.

```
ViewBag.Permissoes = _acessoApp.SelectForeignKey("s8f50f03-c064-4afa-ba5e-397236cd2b03");
```

Para resgatar os dados na view faço o seguinte.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Permissoes)
{
    <li> item.abaNome - item.abaIdSistema </li>
}
```

Como não tenho prática e muito conhecimento em asp.net mvc foi o que eu consegui fazer, não sei se é a melhor forma para fazê-lo. Abaixo segue o código das models das três classes.

```
public partial class Aba
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",    "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Aba()
    {
        this.Tela = new HashSet<Tela>();
    }

    public int idAba { get; set; }
    public string idEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string idAbaSistema { get; set; }

    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tela> Tela { get; set; }
}

public partial class Tela
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Tela()
    {
        this.TelaFuncao = new HashSet<TelaFuncao>();
    }
    public int idTela { get; set; }
    public int idAba { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string idTelaSistema { get; set; }

    public virtual Aba Aba { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TelaFuncao> TelaFuncao { get; set; }
}

public partial class TelaFuncao
{
    public int idTelaFuncao { get; set; }
    public int idTela { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string idFuncaoSistema { get; set; }

    public virtual Tela Tela { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Cadê o `left join`?

Comment: No primeiro exemplo de código, peguei um exemplo na internet e implementei no meu código.

Comment: Comecei a desenvolver em asp.net mvc agr, esta errado?

Comment: Se eu usasse o include resolveria meu problema?

Comment: Estou respondendo sua pergunta. Te peço alguns minutos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há várias coisas que precisam ser ditas para quem vem de outros paradigmas de desenvolvimento, e creio que esta resposta vai ser ideal para isso.

## Premissas de quem vem de outras arquiteturas para ASP.NET MVC e Entity Framework

Primeiro vou fazer esta lista de premissas e aí vamos pro que interessa, que é a solução da sua pergunta.

### 1. Entity Framework não é SQL, nem modelo relacional

Ou seja, tentar "usar um *left join*" no código está errado. O Entity Framework não trabalha assim.

Em primeiro lugar, não dizemos que temos tabelas no Entity Framework: dizemos que temos entidades.

Em segundo lugar, a seleção parte do princípio da carga preguiçosa, que nem tudo que você selecionar será usado de fato na *View*, ao menos que você, programador, diga exatamente o contrário, antecipando a carga.

Em terceiro lugar, LINQ até funciona juntamente com o Entity Framework (até porque o LINQ to Entities é o embrião do Entity Framework, e que veio de outro projeto chamado LINQ to SQL), mas evite de usar. Vai te confundir ainda mais, e não vai ser produtivo, além de que as funções de carga antecipada, monitoramento de registro e configurações *inline* são métodos de extensão que não estão presentes no LINQ.

Pelo que eu entendi do seu código, você quer selecionar todas as funções de todas as telas, que por sua vez estão ligadas a abas. No Entity Framework, você deve visualizar a seleção de dados primeiramente pelo objetivo da seleção (que são justamente as funções de tela) e não selecionar as abas, depois as telas e finalmente as funções. Aprendemos a pensar assim no SQL porque é assim que o SQL funciona melhor, mas no Entity Framework temos uma mudança de paradigma. O que vou fazer é montar uma sentença que selecione as funções, e depois selecionamos o restante das entidades relacionadas.

Outra coisa que vou mostrar pra você é que `SelectForeignKey` não precisa ser implementada. Vamos um passo de cada vez.

Procure tipar todo e qualquer objeto de filtro e de coleção. Tipagem forte é melhor para o desempenho e para a segurança de tipos:

```
public IQueryable<TelaFuncao> SelectForeignKey(string idEmpresa) { ... }
```

Vamos usar, ao invés da sintaxe LINQ, a sintaxe de métodos de extensão, que é mais simples e intuitiva.

```
public IQueryable<TelaFuncao> SelectForeignKey(string idEmpresa) 
{
    return _sigconEntities.TelaFuncao.Where(tf => tf.idEmpresa == idEmpresa);
}
```

> É só isso, Cigano?

É. Só isso já é suficiente para a tela funcionar. E por que?

Porque você já preencheu as relações. O Entity Framework preenche os dados das entidades relacionadas para você. São elas:

```
public partial class Aba
{
    ...

    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tela> Tela { get; set; }
}

public partial class Tela
{
    ...

    public virtual Aba Aba { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TelaFuncao> TelaFuncao { get; set; }
}

public partial class TelaFuncao
{
    ...

    public virtual Tela Tela { get; set; }
}
```

Ou seja, se eu seleciono uma `TelaFuncao`, por exemplo, assim:

```
var telaFuncao = _sigconEntities.TelaFuncao.FirstOrDefault();
```

E fizer isto:

```
var tela = telaFuncao.Tela;
```

`Tela` estará preenchido. Assim como:

```
var aba = telaFuncao.Tela.Aba;
```

`Aba` também estará preenchido.

Da mesma forma, posso ler as N telas de uma aba:

```
var telas = aba.Telas;
```

E as funções de uma tela:

```
var telaFuncoes = tela.TelaFuncoes;
```

Isto é carga preguiçosa. O *framework* se ocupa com a carga e você se ocupa com a lógica sistêmica, que é o que é importante. Se não ficar bom, você pode antecipar a carga.

### 2. *ViewBags* nunca devem conter o dado principal da *View*

Isto é um erro comum de quem está começando no ASP.NET MVC. Toda *View* espera um tipo de dado principal, o qual chamamos *Model* da *View*. Você especifica este tipo dentro da *View* através da anotação `@model`, que normalmente fica na primeira linha do arquivo. No seu caso:

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.TelaFuncao>
```

O *Controller* passa para a *View* o *Model* da *View* através da declaração `return View()`, assim:

```
public ActionResult MinhaSelecaoDeTelaFuncao(Guid id)
{
    var permissoes = SelectForeignKey(id).ToList();
    return View(permissoes);
}
```

Novamente, na *View* para lermos a informação, usamos:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { ... }
```

*ViewBags* servem para montar elementos auxiliares na tela, como, por exemplo, *DropDowns*, algumas descrições, algumas mensagens para o usuário, etc.. Sendo um objeto dinâmico, é perigoso usar *ViewBags* para tudo.

### 3. Escrita de dado dinâmico em tela usa `@`

Faltou uma coisa aqui:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Permissoes)
{
    <li>@item.abaNome - @item.abaIdSistema </li>
}
```

Como alteramos o exemplo para usar `Model`, na verdade fica:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item.Tela.Aba.Nome - @item.Tela.Aba.IdSistema</li>
}
```

### 4. `IQueryable` e `IEnumerable` são duas coisas diferentes.

[Já falei algumas vezes disso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+iqueryable), então vou apenas resumir: `IQueryable` gera um SQL. `IEnumerable` é um resultado de uma geração de SQL.

Vamos agora descartar `SelectForeignKey`. Não precisamos mais dela:

```
public ActionResult MinhaSelecaoDeTelaFuncao(Guid id)
{
    var permissoes = _sigconEntities.TelaFuncao.Where(tf => tf.idEmpresa == id).ToList();
    return View(permissoes);
}
```

Vou fazer ainda melhor: vou separar os dois momentos, o primeiro em que temos `IQueryable` e o segundo que temos `IEnumerable`:

```
public ActionResult MinhaSelecaoDeTelaFuncao(Guid id)
{
    var permissoesQuery = _sigconEntities.TelaFuncao.Where(tf => tf.idEmpresa == id); // Aqui não executamos o SQL ainda
    return View(permissoes.ToList()); // Aqui executamos o SQL
}
```

### 5. Se a tela ficar lenta, antecipe a carga

Carga preguiçosa não resolve tudo. É uma ferramenta poderosa para escrever código rapidamente, mas não é bala de prata.

Na sua tela você vai querer mostrar a permissão, o nome da tela e o nome da aba, imagino. Na carga preguiçosa, para cada permissão, tela e aba que você escrever, pelo menos mais dois `SELECT`s são feitos: um para a tela e outro para a aba.

Vai ficar lento, obviamente.

Para antecipar a carga, usamos o método de extensão [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696450(v=vs.103).aspx) assim:

```
var permissoes = _sigconEntities.TelaFuncao
                   .Include(tf => tf.Tela.Aba)
                   .Where(tf => tf.idEmpresa == id)
                   .ToList();
```

Se quiser ver a *query* gerada, experimente fazer o seguinte:

```
var permissoes = _sigconEntities.TelaFuncao
                   .Include(tf => tf.Tela.Aba)
                   .Where(tf => tf.idEmpresa == id);
var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)permissoes)
        .ToTraceString();
```

### 6. Continue estudando

Isto que eu falei é o básico do básico. Uma mudança de paradigma implica em muita coisa diferente. Procure entender como funciona o *Scaffolding* do ASP.NET MVC, veja as perguntas e respostas aqui do site e, em caso de dúvidas, faça mais perguntas.

Comment: Cara, você é muito fera kkk
Muito obrigado por responder minha pergunta.
Mas seguinte, existem telas que não possuem as funções, como vou achar estas telas?

Comment: Ué. `var telas = _sigconEntities.Telas.Where(t => t.Aba.idEmpresa == id)`.

Comment: Então teria que realizar a consulta duas vezes?

Comment: Acho que não precisa. Você pode também começar a seleção pelas abas, depois obter as telas de cada aba através de `aba.Telas`, e por fim obter as funções de cada tela através de `tela.TelaFuncoes`.

Comment: Entendi, você me ensinou demais Cigano, muito obrigado!
Vou implementar aqui...

Comment: Cigano, surgiu um pequeno problema, não na parte do código acima, mas, quando vou passar os dados para view.
Tenho uma tela de cadastro de acessos, onde vou listar as abas com as telas e funções, a tela de cadastro já é tipada com o model acesso, como vou mandar os dados das abas?

Comment: Faça outra pergunta, por favor.

Comment: beleza, vou fazer agora.

Comment: Fiz a outra pergunta cigano.