# Passar dois modelos para uma view de cadastro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Tenho uma tela de cadastro de acessos. Tenho que preenchê-la com valores cadastrados na base de dados.

Segue os códigos:

Models:

```
public partial class Aba
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Aba()
    {
        this.Tela = new HashSet<Tela>();
    }

    public int idAba { get; set; }
    public string idEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string idAbaSistema { get; set; }

    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tela> Tela { get; set; }
}

public partial class Tela
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Tela()
    {
        this.TelaFuncao = new HashSet<TelaFuncao>();
    }

    public int idTela { get; set; }
    public int idAba { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string idTelaSistema { get; set; }

    public virtual Aba Aba { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TelaFuncao> TelaFuncao { get; set; }
}

public partial class TelaFuncao
{
    public int idTelaFuncao { get; set; }
    public int idTela { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string idFuncaoSistema { get; set; }

    public virtual Tela Tela { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var abas = _abaApp.SelectForeignKey("s8f50f03-c064-4afa-ba5e-397236cd2b03");
return View(abas);
```

Repositório:

```
var abaQuery = _sigconEntities.Aba
                .Where(a => a.idEmpresa == idEmpresa);
return abaQuery.ToList();
```

View:

```
@model Sigcon.Model.Acesso

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cadastrar";
}
```

O problema é enviar o *model* destes valores para a *view*, ela já esta "tipada", não sei como enviar os dois valores.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129742/problema-com-left-join-usando-entity-framework

Comment: Agora você precisa colocar o que você já implementou na sua pergunta. Do jeito que ela está, está muito vago e a pergunta pode ser fechada.

Comment: Beleza, vou editar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar 2 objetos do Controller para a View no C# ASP.Net MVC?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91021/como-enviar-2-objetos-do-controller-para-a-view-no-c-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Muito obrigado bigown! Vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Não é duplicata porque as entidades são relacionadas. A dúvida é sobre a construção estruturada da *View* com as informações selecionadas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seguindo o gancho anterior, se você tem a relação de `Aba` para `Tela`, a seleção feita aqui já contempla a carga preguiçosa de `Tela` e de `TelaFuncao`:

```
var abaQuery = _sigconEntities.Aba
                .Where(a => a.idEmpresa == idEmpresa);
return abaQuery.ToList();
```

`@model` da sua *View*, portanto, precisa ser:

```
@model IEnumerable<Sigcon.Model.Aba>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cadastrar";
}
```

E o preenchimento:

```
@foreach (var aba in Model)
{
    <h1>Aba: @aba.Nome</h1>

    foreach (var tela in aba.Telas) 
    {
        <h2>Tela: @tela.Nome</h1>

        foreach (var permissao in tela.TelaFuncoes)
        {
            <p>Permissão: @permissao.Nome</p>
        }
    }
}
```

---

Mas como você quer um formulário de criação e edição, a solução ficará obrigatoriamente mais complexa. Vou tentar fazer uma resposta sucinta cobrindo todos os pontos.

Antes de mais nada, estamos lidando com uma tela de múltiplas cardinalidades. Minha sugestão é que primeiro você faça uma tela cujo *Model* seja `Tela`, e por ele você possa lidar com N *Models* do tipo `TelaFuncao`. Começar por `Aba` vai tornar a solução muito complexa para você que está começando.

Assim sendo, tomei algumas liberdades e irei reimplementar seu sistema com alguns ajustes, a começar pelos *Models*:

```
public class TelaFuncao
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TelaFuncaoId { get; set; }
    public Guid TelaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Tela Tela { get; set; }
}

public class Tela
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TelaId { get; set; }
    public Guid AbaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Aba Aba { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TelaFuncao> TelaFuncoes { get; set; }
}

public class Aba
{
    [Key]
    public Guid AbaId { get; set; }
    public Guid EmpresaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tela> Telas { get; set; }
}

public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EmpresaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Aba> Abas { get; set; }
}
```

Repare também que estou usando `Guid` de propósito, em detrimento de `int`, na definição das chaves. Há algumas vantagens em se usar [que podem ser achadas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=guid).

Fiz isso porque quero usar as convenções de nomes do Entity Framework e gerar tudo automaticamente usando *Scaffolding*. Feito isso, podemos gerar *Controllers* e *Views* através da IDE.

Para isso, depois de ter definido os 4 *Models*, clico com o botão direito no diretório `Controllers` e escolho a opção **Add** > **Controller...**:

[image: Add Controller]

Na tela seguinte, escolha **MVC 5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework**:

[image: MVC 5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework]

Logo após, defina a *Model class*, a classe do contexto de dados e o nome do *Controller*. Aqui fiz para `Empresa`. Ficou assim:

[image: EmpresasController]

Clicando em *Add*, o resultado deve ser:

[image: Controller gerado]

Repare que não apenas a lógica de seleção, detalhamento, inclusão, edição e exclusão foram geradas, mas também as *Views* correspondentes de cada operação.

Repita o processo, para Abas, Telas e Funções de Telas.

Feito isso, será necessário instalar um pacote chamado [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). [Já falei muito sobre ele aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem), então vou pular algumas partes.

Abra o **Package Manager Console** (**View** > **Other Windows** > **Package Manager Console**) e instale-o.

[image: BeginCollectionItem]

Abra `TelasController` (estou supondo que você já gerou ele) e `Views/Telas/Create.cshtml`. Vamos começar pela *View*. A minha está assim:

```
@model MeuProjeto.Models.Tela

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Tela</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AbaId, "AbaId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("AbaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AbaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Entre o botão "Create" e o último campo, `Nome`, coloque uma declaração de chamada de *Partial*, assim:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.Partial("_Permissoes", Model.TelaFuncoes)

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ou seja, estamos mandando para outra *View* (no caso, uma *View* parcial) apenas `TelaFuncoes`. Lá montaremos nossa lista de permissões.

Crie uma *Partial* chamada "_Permissoes":

[image: Partials (1)]

[image: Partials (2)]

Coloque dentro dela o seguinte:

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.TelaFuncao>

<div class="actions">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="adicionar-nova-permissao">
        Adicionar Nova Permissão
    </a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#adicionar-nova-permissao").click(function () {
                    $.get('/Telas/NovaLinhaPermissao', function (template) {
                        $("#area-permissoes").append(template);
                    });
                });
    </script>
</div>

<div id="area-permissoes">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var permissao in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_LinhaPermissao", permissao);
        }
    }
</div>
```

Bom, se você ler o código, notará que vamos precisar de mais uma *Partial* chamada `_LinhaPermissao`. Crie esta *Partial* e coloque dentro dela o seguinte:

```
@model MeuProjeto.Models.TelaFuncao

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("TelaFuncoes"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TelaFuncaoId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TelaId)

        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Nome</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nome" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a class="btn red" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();">Excluir</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Se você fez tudo certo, a tela deve aparecer assim:

[image: Tela Criar]

Se você reparou, no nosso `TelasController`, precisamos adicionar um método chamado `NovaLinhaPermissao`. Ele é assim:

```
    public ActionResult NovaLinhaPermissao()
    {
        return PartialView("_LinhaPermissao", new TelaFuncao { TelaFuncaoId = Guid.NewGuid() });
    }
```

E agora podemos adicionar e excluir permissões.

[image: BeginCollectionItem em ação]

E, quando adicionamos 3 permissões e mandamos para `Create` de `TelasController`, temos as 3 permissões lá.

[image: Fim!]

Como exercício, faça agora a edição. Se precisar de ajuda, abra outra pergunta (essa já ficou grande demais).

PS: Elimine um repositório da sua arquitetura. O Entity Framework já é um repositório.

Comment: Cigano, a tela de acesso é uma de cadastro, como eu recuperaria os valores de acesso?

Comment: Vou remover o repositório, vlw pela dica.

Comment: Ah, você quer tipo um formulário de edição?

Comment: Isso mesmo, tenho os valores do acesso e embaixo tenho as permissões de todo o sistema, aí cadastro tudo.

Comment: Isto é uma terceira pergunta. Recomendo você linkar a próxima pergunta com esta daqui.

Comment: Mas oque escrevo na próxima? É a mesma pergunta não é não?

Comment: Posso responder nesta. Vai ficar enorme. Ok?

Comment: Pode sim, acho que a segunda pergunta ficaria igual.

Comment: Falei que ia ficar enorme.

Comment: Era isso mesmo Cigano, mas estava com problema na hora de listar e editar kkk
Mas você melhorou demais meus códigos, agora consigo fazer o restante, se precisar abro outra pergunta. Obrigado!