# Recuperar valores IEnumerable da View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma tabela/model chamada ItemTabelaPreco:

```
public class ItemTabelaPreco
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorUnitario { get; set; }
    public int QtdPacote { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorPacote { get; set; }
    public int TabelaPrecoId { get; set; }
}
```

E outra chamada TabelaPreco:

```
public class TabelaPreco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemTabelaPreco> ListaItemTabelaPreco { get; set; }
}
```

Na view da TabelaPreco carrego a ListaItemTabelaPreco sem problemas:

```
@model Aplicativo.Models.TabelaPreco

@foreach (var list in Model.ListaItemTabelaPreco)
{
    @Html.Raw(list.Nome)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => list.ValorUnitario)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => list.QtdPacote)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => list.ValorPacote)
}
```

O problema que tenho está na hora de recuperar os valores dessa lista da view na edição da TabelaPreco no controller após o post, já tentei de várias formas e sempre vem a lista vazia, os outros campos que não são dessa lista, vem os valores corretamente:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(TabelaPreco tabelaPrecoModel)
{
    tabelaPrecoModel.ListaItemTabelaPreco VEM SEMPRE NULL.
}
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Eu acho que tenho a solução, preciso só de umas informações pra ter certeza. Sua view é para EDITAR a ListaItemTabelaPreco ou para você ADICIONAR novos itens a ela?

Comment: Bom dia @FabriDamazio, realmente esqueci de informar isso, preencho a propriedade da class `TabelaPreco` no Get da view Edit:

`IEnumerable<ItemTabelaPreco> ListaItemTabelaPreco`

Na view Edit eu rodo o `foreach` para exibir a lista de itens da `ListaItemTabelaPreco` ao clica no botão de Salvar que da um Post através do `ActionResult Edit`, porém, essa lista vem sempre vazia.

Comment: Voce sabe usar ViewModels?

Comment: @FabriDamazio Já utilizei, mas não sei se de forma correta, mas se você puder esclarecer um pouco a forma correta de uso, acredito que consigo usar sim.

Comment: [Um clássico problema de cardinalidade 1:N, resolvível pelo uso do BeginCollectionItem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=begincollectionitem).

Comment: [Se precisar de um tutorial, use esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129911/passar-dois-modelos-para-uma-view-de-cadastro/129912#129912).

Answer (score -1):

Exprimenta mudar o foeach por um for tradicional

```
  @for (int i = 0; i != Model.ListaItemTabelaPreco.Count(); ++i)
 {
@Html.Raw(list.Nome)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ListaItemTabelaPreco[i].ValorUnitario)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> Model.ListaItemTabelaPreco[i].QtdPacote)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ListaItemTabelaPreco[i].ValorPacote)
 }
```

Comment: Neste caso não há nenhuma diferença entre o `foreach` e o `for`, a sua resposta não faz sentido.

Comment: Não existe o parâmetro `index` para identificar a linha, e o *ModelBinder* não tem como predizer a cardinalidade N. Além disso, esta solução não garante a remontagem do formulário em caso de falha de validação, por exemplo.